# Pause a effect and resume

Tags: apache-flex

I wish to create a effect on a component when the mouseover it. and when the mouseout, the effect will be reversed.

```
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Parallel id="move">
                <s:Move3D id="moveDown"  yBy="+100"/>
                <s:Pause  />
                <s:Move3D id="moveUp"  yBy="-100"/>
        </s:Parallel>
    </fx:Declarations>

<s:Panel id="userMenu" includeIn="USER" x="920" y="35" width="689" height="142"

             mouseOver="move.play(Array(userMenu), false)" 
             mouseOut="move.resume(Array(userMenu), false)"
             rotationZ="180" >
        <s:HGroup x="44" y="9" width="590" height="62" gap="15" horizontalCenter="1" rotationZ="180"
                  verticalCenter="1"
                  x.USER="10" y.USER="208">

        </s:HGroup>
    </s:Panel>
```

But I received a error like this

```
1152: A conflict exists with inherited definition mx.core:UIComponent.move in namespace public mx.core:IFlexDisplayObject.
```

after I add the `move.resume()` function. Why I receive this error? and How to debug it?

Comment: Just guessing here, that error doesn't make sense to me. Try removing the arguments to the `resume()` method -- the documentation says this function has no arguments, just do: `move.resume()`. If that doesn't help, try changing the `id` of your `Paralell` effect to something other than "move" (perhaps there is some weird conflict w/the "move" event that a UIComponent defines).

Comment: your guessing is right, "move" cannot used as a id. and the error gone. thanks.